# Error with DialogFragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

On click i want display a dialog but i get an error in the `show` word. This part of code is in my MainActivity that extends and Activity.. Instead, the dialog i want display, is created in another class that extends `DialogFragment`.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             DialogFragment df=new DialogTrial();
                             df.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");
```

The error:

```
The method show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String) in the type DialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments (android.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)
```

I tried everything: `this.getFragmentManager()`, `getActivity()`, `context`, `this`but always same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are passing wrong Fragment manager..
Change this line

```
 df.show(this.getFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");
```

into

```
df.show(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");
```

Comment: I tried but i get: `The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity`

Comment: is your MainActivity extends FragmentActivy??

Comment: Nope.. extends `Activity`..have i to extends FragmentActivity in any case?

Comment: yes like **public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity**

Comment: @End.Game You can accept the answer if it helped you. Upvotes are really an encouragement for SO users :-)

Comment: Thank you very much.I am expecting this one :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the support package, please check your imports:

I think you are mixing classes from support package and not.

If you use support package:

1. make your activity `extends FragmentActivity`.
2. Use `getSupportFragmentManager()`
3. check all imports for example: `import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;`